# C# lock - and "readonly lock()"?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

In my Application I have various threads `reading` data from collections. Say, there are 20 readers. One Thread is responsible for periodically refreshing that collection with new data.

Now, using the `lock` statement from within all threads (reader and writer) will have the drawback, that the readers block each other as well. Simplified Example:

```
private readonly object lockObj = new Object();
private List<String>() data;

public void dataReader1(){
   lock(lockObj){
      //read...
   }
}

public void dataReader2(){
   lock(lockObj){
      //read...
   }
}

public void dataReader3(){
   lock(lockObj){
      //read...
   }
}

public void dataWriter(){
   lock(lockObj){
      //write write write...
   }
}
```

Obviously now only one reader can access the data at the time.

To overcome this issue, I could use a global writeLock and different read lock objects like this:

```
private  List<String>() data;

private readonly object writeLock = new Object();
private readonly object readLock1 = new Object();
private readonly object readLock2 = new Object();
private readonly object readLock3 = new Object();

public void dataReader1(){
   lock(readLock1){
      //read...
   }
}

public void dataReader2(){
   lock(readLock2){
      //read...
   }
}

public void dataReader3(){
   lock(readLock3){
      //read...
   }
}

public void dataWriter(){
   lock(readLock1){
      lock(readLock2){
         lock(readLock3){
             lock(writeLock){
                //write write write...
             }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Now, every thread can read - until the writer starts to lock them out, till he finally got the exclusive write Lock.

I don't really like this approach, because nesting locks smells like dead-lock incoming sooner or later. So, I wonder if there is a native way to achieve this with a single lock statement?

Thinking of something like ...

```
private readonly object lockObj= new Object();
private List<String>() data;

public void dataReader1(){
   readonly lock(lockObj){
      //read...
   }
}

public void dataReader2(){
   readonly lock(lockObj){
      //read...
   }
}

public void dataReader3(){
   readonly lock(lockObj){
      //read...
   }
}

public void dataWriter(){
   lock(lockObj){
      //write write write...
   }
}
```

... where C# is able to understand, that `readonly lock` can be entered, unless there is a `lock` in place (or trying to be aquired) - and that `lock` in turn is waiting, until there is no more existing `readonly lock`.

Comment: [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=net-7.0)...?

Comment: Don't lock on public objects: `lock(data)`.

Comment: @canton7 That looks about what I'm locking.. ehm.. looking for :)

Comment: @Enigmativity yeah. just a simplified example.

Comment: There are in fact [Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock#guidelines) for what to lock on, _and what not_.

Comment: @dognose - Don't over simplify. Make the question real or you confuse future readers. In other words, don't make assumptions.

Comment: @Enigmativity updated that part, so future readers don't get confused anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you are looking for [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=net-7.0), e.g.

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable {
  private ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

  // Same for DataReader2, DataReader3 etc. 
  public void DataReader1() {
    _lock.EnterReadLock();

    try { // Relevant Code here
    }
    finally {
      _lock.ExitReadLock();
    }
  }

  public void DataWriter() {
    _lock.EnterWriteLock();

    try { // Relevant Code here
    }
    finally {
      _lock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
  }

  public void Dispose() => Dispose(true);

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
    if (disposing) {
      _lock.Dispose(); 
    }
  }
}
```

So several *readers* can share the resource, but *writer* has the exclusive access.